# Loading message shown on $routeChangeStart disappears as soon as LESS CSS starts compiling

Tags: angularjs, less

I've created a pretty heavy AngularJS application which has many dependencies (JS libraries and LESS css). When the application URL is hit, it determines the route based on login status and redirects to login route if not logged in. The problem is, until the route is redirected to, and the HTML is loaded, the page remains completely blank for almost 4-5 seconds, which looks really confusing.

I tried to implement some message using $routeChangeStart but it's not giving me the desired results. I want the 'loading..." message as soon as URL is hit and until app is routed and HTML is fully loaded. But the message is disappearing after a couple of milliseconds.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
  $rootScope.layout.loading = true;
});

$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
  $rootScope.layout.loading = false;
});
```

UPDATE: The problem seems to be the LESS CSS which is being compiled and loaded to get the page ready. The loading indicator text correctly works without LESS CSS (see [this Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WN38qe693NCzrqfZsBha?p=preview))

In the actual application, I have put the loading indicator text after the body tag, and there are many JS scripts (including LESS.js) after the indicator text. The loading indicator shows until LESS starts compiling, and disappears as after compilation starts. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe .run() method of angular can solve your issue, Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kick start the application. It is executed after all of the services have been configured and the injector has been created.

You can try the following to show/hide loader when your application is loading.

```html
.run(['$location', function ($location) {    
  // if your application URL os https://myApplication/Login/loginStatus
        if ($location.path() === '' && $location.$$absUrl.indexOf('/loginStatus') > -1) {
   // show loading
   // some code here to return route based on login status for example,
   var promise = getLoginStatus();
   promise.then(function (result) {
    // redirect to the route as per login status   
    $location.path(result); //Where result is route url.
    // hide loading   
   });   
        }
    }]);
```